# How do I check the NHibernate version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm supposed to start working on a project written in ASP.NET MVC2, using NHibernate. I'm more familiar with Entity Framework.

Is there a way I can check which NHibernate's version the application is using?

Comment: Just look at the version number of the NHibernate assembly referenced by the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On visual studio, go to project using nhibernate then open references folder, righ click over `nhibernate` assembly and click properties. You'll should be able to see the the version.

You could do something similar outside visual studio, right clicking over `nhibernate.dll` and checking assembly version on `details` tab.

Comment: I was a little confused because because right-clicking the reference in was giving me runtime-version and version at the same time. Going to where the file is located solved the problem. Thank you so much.